# Регистрация приложения AppStore

Tags: appstore

Всем. Привет.
Есть приложение c объявлениями по аренде саун на определенное время, с возможностью оплаты этой услуги через  яндекс кассы.

Само приложение является бесплатным.

Так как приложением будет принимать оплаты на юридическое лицо через яндекс кассы, возможна регистрация данного приложения в app store на физическое лицо или все же  нужно регистрировать на юр. лицо?

Comment: Нашли ответ на этот вопрос? Тоже столкнулись с этим.

Comment: К сожелению нет.